# NVM / Node installation. Command not recognised

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, nvm

Ubuntu Linux 20.04.

Setting up a new machine I installed the lastest version of npm.  At the time that was v17.4.0.  For some reason it also has folders for v17.3.0 in `/home/dougi/.nvm/versions/node`.

I then found I needed the LTS version for certain things and so used nvm to install v16.13.2.

I uninstalled v17.4.0 with `nvm uninstall v17.4.0` which removed all traces of v17.4.0, but left the folders for v17.3.0 (no idea why they are there).

Today I installed ionic cli with `npm install -g @ionic/cli` and it puts the ionic files in `/home/dougi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.3.0/bin`.  When I run `ionic start` I get `Command 'ionic' not found...`.  Using `nvm ls` I can see that I am currently using v16.13.2, so I'm unsure why ionic is being installed to the v17.3.0 folder.  I assume that this is why the ionic command is not recognised.  Output from `nvm ls` is:

[image]

I also note a lot of red, which may be bad?

What I am doing wrong please?

How do I get rid of the v17.3.0 folders (I assume not good to just delete them)?

How do I get ionic to install and be recognised under node v16.13.2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try to delete that manually using:

```
cd ~/.nvm/versions/node
sudo rm -rf v17.4.0/
```

and also make sure that you are actually switched to the 16 version:

```
nvm install 16
nvm use 16
nvm alias default 16
```

Comment: Thank you. I was assuming that it would cause problems to just delete the folders.  Is it ok to do that?  It won't cause other problems?

Comment: No not at all you can reinstall that with nvm again

Comment: Thanks I just did that and `nvm ls` now lists `node -> stable (-> v16.13.2) (default)` and `stable -> 16.13 (-> v16.13.2) (default)` which looks good. But then I do `npm install -g @ionic/cli` and it just re-creates the folders I just deleted and puts the ionic file in the newly created `/home/dougi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.3.0/bin` folder again.  It's like it thinks I have v17.3.0 installed, but I don't.

Comment: could you please rerun the steps and just before installing the ionic, run `which npm` and make sure that is use the v16 npm?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, when I do that I get `/home/dougi/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/npm`

Comment: If I do `nvm use system` I get `Now using system version of node: v14.19.0 (npm v8.3.0)`.  In case that's helpful.

Comment: sorry but I didn't catch that at the end, so is it working now?

Comment: Unfortunately not no. Same issue :(

Comment: Please also rerun the steps and just before installation, run `nvm cache clear`. and also do uninstall  it via nvm and then manually remove it

Comment: Thank you. Just tried that and unfortunately no change.  Still creates v17.3.0 folders and places the files in there.

Comment: Please could you try this:
nvm uninstall 16;
nvm install 16;
nvm use 16;
and then install the ionic ?

Comment: Thanks.  It's very strange. I just completely removed nvm and completely removed nodejs using apt-get.  I then re-installed nvm and did the `nvm install 16` `nvm use 16` and `nvm alias default 16`. All looks fine when I do `nvm ls` showing 16 as the default etc. I do `npm install -g @ionic/cli` and it creates the v17.3.0 folders again. I've no idea where it's getting the v17.3.0 from. As per your request, the steps I just did do the same, so no change, unfortunately.

Comment: Interesting one. Running `npm root -g` shows the installation root for global node modules and that returns `/home/dougi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.3.0/lib/node_modules`

Comment: I've got it.  Will put detail in the answer!  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear it

Answer (score 0):

When running nvm to manage node you don't want to use the global prefix in npm as nvm needs to manage that.

I had a global npm prefix set and so all npm installations going to the path of the node version in the npm prefix.

You can check your npm global prefix with:

`npm root -g`

Deleting that prefix then enables nvm to decide which node version to install into.  To delete the global npm prefix:

`npm config delete prefix`

nvm now worked properly and when I ran `npm install -g @ionic/cli` it  properly installed to the version of node currently selected in nvm.  Phew!

Thank you to @sina.ce for his help in getting me there!